# Drop range of columns by labels

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I had this large data frame:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J ...   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ...  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
1  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35 ...  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
2  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61 ...  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77

[3 rows x 26 columns]
```

which you can create using

```
alphabet = [chr(letter_i) for letter_i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3*26).reshape(3, 26), columns=alphabet)
```

---

**What's the best way to drop all columns between column `'D'` and `'R'` using the labels of the columns?**

I found one ugly way to do it:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.get_loc('D'):df.columns.get_loc('R')+1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my entry:

```
>>> df.drop(df.columns.to_series()["D":"R"], axis=1)
    A   B   C   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   0   1   2  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
1  26  27  28  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
2  52  53  54  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77
```

By converting `df.columns` from an `Index` to a `Series`, we can take advantage of the `["D":"R"]`-style selection:

```
>>> df.columns.to_series()["D":"R"]
D        D
E        E
F        F
G        G
H        H
I        I
J        J
...    ...
Q        Q
R        R
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
print df.ix[:,'A':'C'].join(df.ix[:,'S':'Z'])

Out[1]: 
    A   B   C   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   0   1   2  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
1  26  27  28  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
2  52  53  54  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77
```

Comment: Edited to cut out instead of extract. This should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way ...

```
low, high = df.columns.get_slice_bound(('D', 'R'), 'left')
drops = df.columns[low:high+1]
print df.drop(drops, axis=1)


    A   B   C   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
0   0   1   2  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
1  26  27  28  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
2  52  53  54  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy for more flexibility ... numpy allows comparison of letters (probably by comparing on ASCII bit level, or something):

```
import numpy as np
array = (['A','B','C','D'])
array > 'B'
print(array)
print(array>'B')
```

gives:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
array([False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

More difficult selections are also easily possible:

```
b[np.logical_and(b>'B', b<'D')]
```

gives:

```
array(['C'], 
  dtype='|S1')
```